# Unable to install Ruby using rvm in Linux Mint 21

Tags: ruby, rvm

While I was trying to install Ruby using rvm I couldn't. It is returning error '__rvm_make -j12' which is not available on internet, can anyone help me with this. I installed normal apt but it was not recognized by Shopify installation, so I though of installing from rvm.
Thanks in advance.

I used the following commands in sequence

```
sudo gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
sudo apt install software-properties-common
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER
echo 'source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
Restart PC
rvm list known
rvm install 3.0.0
```

Then it installs dependencies and libraries,

```
ruby-3.0.0 - #extracting ruby-3.0.0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-3.0.0...
ruby-3.0.0 - #configuring...
ruby-3.0.0 - #post-configuration..
ruby-3.0.0 - #compiling... ERROR
```